# How to write extracted result in csv file using beanshell jmeter?

Tags: csv, arraylist, jmeter, filewriter, beanshell

I am getting HTTP response in JSON format. Using JSON extractor I am able to extract exact value but I am not able to store them in CSV file.

JSON response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "vulns":     [
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "82003",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696056"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "90067",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696057"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "70000",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696058"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "70032",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696059"
        },
                {
            "TYPE": "vuln",
            "ID": "90042",
            "FQDN": "",
            "PORT": "",
            "Table": "67696060"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I want All the ID to be stored in .csv file to use them in future.
I used following code in `beanshell postprocessor`

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

String str=vars.get("ID");

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Softwares\\Installed\\jmeter-3.0\\bin\\ID.csv"); 

writer.write(str);

writer.close();
```

It is writting the file but all the ID's are written in one line like

```
["82003","90067","70000","70032","90042"]
```

but I need them like

```
82003
90067
70000
70032
90042
```

Debug postprocessor response data

```
ID=["82003","90067","70000","70032","90042"]
```

can some please provide me solution or BeanShell code for the same?

thanks,
Vijay

Comment: please add the pattern/regex that you used in order to retrieve the `ID`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can kill two birds with one stone using JSR223 PostProcessor and Groovy language instead of JSON Extractor and Beanshell.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which produces that JSON output
2. Put the following code into PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

   JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
   def json = slurper.parseText(response)

   def ID = json.vulns.ID

   ID.each { FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("C:\\Softwares\\Installed\\jmeter-3.0\\bin\\ID.csv"), it + System.getProperty("line.separator"), true) }
   ```

You should get the file generated in the format you want.

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Answer (score 2):

try this, it worked for me

```
ID=vars.get("ID");

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Softwares\\Installed\\jmeter-3.0\\bin\\ID.csv",true); // true to append 

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
 out.write(ID);
 out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 out.close();

writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting the exact value using a JSON Extractor, you can use the following code to write variables in new line.

```
    try {
      extractedId=vars.get("extracted_Id");
      f= new FileOutputStream("D:/YourCSVFile.csv", **true**);
      p = new PrintStream(f); 
      this.interpreter.setOut(p);
      print(extractedId);
      f.close();
   }

  catch (Throwable ex) {
     log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
     throw ex;
  }
```

In the FileOutputStream function use **'false'**, if you want to create new fresh results in every setup. Putting **'true'** will append into the same file in your every run of that Test plan